# Using same control variables as in propensity score matching

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, stata, propensity-scores

I matched my treatment and control group in STATA, using propensity score matching. I also made sure that each treatment/control pair share the same industry and year ( it's a panel data).
If  I'm now running a regression using this matched sample-  do I or don't I have to include the industry and year fixed effects as control variables in the regression?

Thanks